Flutter: Create a book like Swiper in Flutter, that can swipe between Books and Chapters. (Forward and Backward)
I have a Bible screen where the user can swipe between books. The books are:  "Genesis", "Leviticus", "Exodus",..... "Mathew", "Mark",.... "Revelation".
Each book has separate chapters like 1,2,3,4,5 and each chapters have different Verses.
What i want is that, when user swipes RIGHT from the Last Chapter of any book, The next page should be the 1st Chapter of next Adjacent Book, And when the user swipes LEFT from the 1st chapter, then user should see the Last Chapter of Previous Book.
Been Stuck to this Problem for some days.
Here is a simple Code for what i am doing. I may be completely Doing this wrong please correct me or please do mention any solutions.
I tried adding the book to the new list, but this was causing some problems to the other methods in the bible logic.
// ignore_for_file: public_member_api_docs, sort_constructors_first
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class Book {
  final String bookName;
  final List<Chapter> chapters;

  Book({required this.bookName, required this.chapters});
}

class Chapter {
  final int chapterNumber;
  final List<String> verse;
  Chapter({
    required this.chapterNumber,
    required this.verse,
  });
}

var data = [
  Book(
    bookName: "Genesis",
    chapters: [
      Chapter(chapterNumber: 1, verse: ["1", "2", "3"]),
      Chapter(chapterNumber: 2, verse: ["1", "2", "3"]),
      Chapter(chapterNumber: 3, verse: ["1", "2", "3"]),
    ],
  ),
  Book(
    bookName: "Exodus",
    chapters: [
      Chapter(chapterNumber: 1, verse: ["1", "2", "3"]),
      Chapter(chapterNumber: 2, verse: ["1", "2", "3"]),
      Chapter(chapterNumber: 3, verse: ["1", "2", "3"]),
    ],
  ),
  Book(
    bookName: "Leviticus",
    chapters: [
      Chapter(chapterNumber: 1, verse: ["1", "2"]),
      Chapter(chapterNumber: 2, verse: ["1", "2"]),
    ],
  ),
  Book(
    bookName: "Numbers",
    chapters: [
      Chapter(chapterNumber: 1, verse: ["1", "2", "3", "4"]),
      Chapter(chapterNumber: 2, verse: ["1", "2", "3", "4"]),
      Chapter(chapterNumber: 3, verse: ["1", "2", "3", "4"]),
    ],
  ),
  Book(
    bookName: "Deuteronomy",
    chapters: [
      Chapter(chapterNumber: 1, verse: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]),
    ],
  ),
];

class BiblePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const BiblePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<BiblePage> createState() => _BiblePageState();
}

class _BiblePageState extends State<BiblePage> {
  PageController pageController = PageController();
  PageController chapterController = PageController();

  ScrollPhysics? chapterPhysics;
  bool isLastChapter = false;
  bool isFirstChapter = true;
  int currentChapterIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    chapterController.addListener(_l1);
    pageController.addListener(_l2);
  }

  _l2() {
    print(pageController.position.userScrollDirection);
    // print("---->>>${pageController.positions.first.userScrollDirection}");
    bool isForward =
        pageController.position.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.forward;
    bool isReverse =
        pageController.position.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.reverse;
    if (isForward) {
      changePhysics(const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics());
    } else if (isReverse) {
      changePhysics(const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics());
    }
  }

  _l1() {
    print(chapterController.position.userScrollDirection);
    bool isForward = chapterController.position.userScrollDirection ==
        ScrollDirection.forward;
    bool isReverse = chapterController.position.userScrollDirection ==
        ScrollDirection.reverse;
    final extentAfter = chapterController.position.extentAfter;

    log(isFirstChapter.toString());
    log(chapterPhysics.toString());

    if (isForward && isFirstChapter) {
      previousPage();
      // changePhysics(const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics());
      changePhysics(const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics());
    } else if (isLastChapter && isReverse) {
      changePhysics(const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics());
    }

    log(chapterPhysics.toString());
  }

  final duration = const Duration(milliseconds: 300);
  final curve = Curves.ease;
  previousPage() {
    pageController.previousPage(duration: duration, curve: curve);
  }

  nextPage() {
    pageController.nextPage(duration: duration, curve: curve);
  }

  void changePhysics(ScrollPhysics physics) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      setState(() {
        chapterPhysics = physics;
      });
    });
  }

  changeIsLastChapter(bool val) {
    setState(() {
      isLastChapter = val;
      isFirstChapter = false;
    });
  }

  changeIsFirstChapter(bool val) {
    setState(() {
      isLastChapter = false;
      isFirstChapter = val;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    chapterController.removeListener(_l1);
    chapterController.removeListener(_l2);
    pageController.dispose();
    chapterController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Bible App'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: PageView.builder(
          key: const PageStorageKey<String>("PageView"),
          onPageChanged: (v) {
            changeIsLastChapter(false);
            changeIsFirstChapter(currentChapterIndex == 0);
          },
          controller: pageController,
          itemCount: data.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, bookIndex) {
            final book = data[bookIndex];
            return Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(40),
              child: PageView.builder(
                key: PageStorageKey<String>("chapterView$bookIndex"),
                controller: chapterController,
                itemCount: book.chapters.length,
                physics: chapterPhysics,
                onPageChanged: (v) {
                  if (v == book.chapters.length - 1) {
                    changeIsLastChapter(true);
                  } else if (v == 0) {
                    changeIsFirstChapter(true);
                  } else {
                    changeIsLastChapter(false);
                    changeIsFirstChapter(false);
                  }

                  setState(() {
                    currentChapterIndex = v;
                  });
                },
                itemBuilder: (context, chapterIndex) {
                  final chapter = book.chapters[chapterIndex];
                  return Center(
                    child: Text(
                        'BOOK: ${book.bookName} - Chapter: ${chapter.chapterNumber} '),
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I tried creating a new Temp list and adding it, but this was causing other indexing problem for the verses and Highlighting the paragraph.

Don,t maintain index for chapter rather then maintain index for the book in list. On page change just check if the current index is less then or greater then for current book and add things accordingly. You do not need to maintain two variable just for that. This will work if you have some back or forward btn for changing books. But in your case where you want to scroll continuously. You do need a temporary list and for index when making this list just add two more variable in it one define book index and other one for chapter. or use custom fn to calculate it.
